# Unexpected output of Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am using the `Popen` constructor from `subprocess` to capture the output of the command that I am running in my python script:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["my-cli", "ls", "/mypics/"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()

print(output)
print(output.count('jpg'))
```

My objective is to save the output file names as an array of strings.

However, when I print the `output`, I notice that instead of saving file names as strings, the script saves each byte (letter) of each file as a string.  Therefore, the printed output looks like this

f
i
l
e
.
j
p
g

1

So instead of printing one filename `file.jpg` I am getting a printout of the 8 separate characters that make up the filename.  But running the `ls` command in the terminal directly will just list the filenames row by row as it should.

What am I doing wrong in this script and what is the workaround here? I am running Python 2.7 Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What was that `my-cli` inside your `Popen array`. I think some new line character where appending after each char output. Just remove that `my-cli` and this could fork for you.

```
p = Popen(["ls", "/mypics/"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: the cli command is needed as I am using a method form the cli itself called `ls`